# Import _nlopt.pyd error in OSX

Tags: python, macos, nlopt

I followed step with [nlopt](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt)
and get a _nlopt.pyd

When i try to use nlopt.py(it's have code like follow)

```
import _nlopt
```

and it's gives

```
ImportError: No module named _nlopt
```

I am sure  the _nlopt.pyd is in the folder

And it's work in Windows7

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you first configured with the `--enable-shared` flag before compiling

Comment: Then remember to tell the operating system where to find the shared library adding the path to the installed libraries to your `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable (e.g. in your `~/.profile` file).